# Jqgrid not showing data on reloading when using GroupView and loadonce as true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 4.6 with loadonce true and grouping by a column. I have also sorted the data coming from server as per documentation of grouping given [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping). But I can't see any data in my grid when I try to reload the data using below code

```
jQuery("#RamTargetTable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Below is the code

```
jQuery("#RamTargetTable").jqGrid({
                    url: '<%=Url.Content("~/RamTarget/GetTargetData")%>',
                    width: 1220,
                    height: 250,
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: [my column names],
                    colModel: [my model],
                    emptyrecords: 'No Turbines found for the selected Plant',
                    searchoptions: { searchhidden: true },
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    loadonce: true,
                    hidegrid: false,
                    rowList: [],
                    pager: '#RamTargetTablePager',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "RAM Targets",
                    pgbuttons: false,
                    pginput: false,
                    pgtext: null,
                    grouping: true,
                    groupingView: {
                        groupField: ['SerialNumber'],
                        groupColumnShow: [true],
                        hideFirstGroupCol: [true]
                    },
                    editurl: '<%=Url.Content("~/RamTarget/AddEditRamTargets")%>',
                    checkOnSubmit: false,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: true
                });

                $('#RamTargetTable').jqGrid('navGrid', '#RamTargetTablePager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true});


function SendPlantId() {
                var plantId = $("#lstPlant").val() == null ? 0 : $("#lstPlant").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=Url.Content("~/RamTarget/FilterGrid")%>',
                    type: "post",
                    data: { id: plantId, filter: "Plant" },
                    success: function(data) {
jQuery("#RamTargetTable").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                               }
                    });
                   }
```

Comment: hi @ashish your question is unclear please can you provide more details and why you want to replicate button's behavior ?

Comment: @hiteshtr the inbuilt refresh button on pager, reloads the data from server. Hence  i want to reload data from my SendPlantId function. Addtionally the text area(bottom right of grid) which shows number of records also gets updated, but i can't see them in the grid

Comment: @hiteshtr Updated the question and description.